# Javascript time difference error

Tags: javascript, date

I have have issues with the Javascript below. I am trying to get a countdown clock done, but the result I am getting is off i.e. the below due time of 1900 hrs today

Gives 11:44:00 left when the current time is 17:16:00. It should be 1 hour and 44 minutes. It is adding 10 hours somewhere.

Any ideas on where I went wrong have rewritten this already with the same result. I know it is not clean code yet. I am just prototyping atm.

Regards,

```
var countDownDueTime = new Date('September 26, 2015 19:00:00')

function updateClock() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    //Pad time to make 2 digit minutes and seconds
    currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
    currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

    var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;

    $("#clock").html(currentTimeString);
    countDown(currentTime);
}

function countDown(currentTime) {
    var difference = new Date(countDownDueTime - currentTime);
    var currentHours = difference.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = difference.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = difference.getSeconds();

    //Pad time to make 2 digit minutes and seconds
    currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
    currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

    var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;

    $("#countDown").html(currentTimeString);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
})
```

Comment: The time remaining until `September 26, 2015 19:00:00` is dependent on timezone, but you don't specify the timezone, so it will use the timezone of the client machine. Clients in different timezones will see different values for the time remaining.

Comment: It's possible your fix is as simple as adding the timezone after the deadline: `new Date('September 26, 2015 19:00:00 UTC')`

Comment: btw, you should change `setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);` to `setInterval(updateClock, 1000);`. There is no sense making a string and having setTimeout eval it when you're just trying to pass it a function

Comment: All that being said by paulpro, i'd only add that you pass your current time from server..

Comment: Thanks @Paulpro I subtracted 36000000(10hours) from my difference and it fixed it. Also updated the setInterval()

Comment: You're welcome, Ashley. I'm glad that I could help. Note that if you subtract 10 hours, you'll still end up with different results in different timezones ( it may fix it in yours but make it worse in others ). It would probably be better to add a timezone to your deadline, like 'UTC' (it's good to measure times it UTC/GMT since it's recognized everywhere in the world)